# Technique/script to extract AD and computer information and UEFISecureBootEnabled status

Tags: powershell

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter 'enabled -eq "true"' `
-Properties Name,Operatingsystem,OperatingSystemVersion,IPv4Address |
Sort-Object -Property Operatingsystem |
Select-Object -Property Name,Operatingsystem,OperatingSystemVersion,IPv4Address
```

I believe somehow combining the script above and below using a for loop.

```
Get-ItemProperty ` -Path hklm:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecureBoot\State ` | Select-Object UEFISecureBootEnabled
```

In time I'd like to "assemble" other commands to extract reports/data.  I'd like help to learn and create a script I can modify with other commands.